# Is it possible to downgrade server 2012 to server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, license

We have purchased a server 2012 license, however the software we need to use only works with 2008 R2.

I have already installed and activated server 2012, is it possible to downgrade to 2008 R2 or have I gone too far and need to purchase a new 2008 R2 license.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There will be no technical down-grade, it'll be a wipe and reinstall.  I'm assuming you realize that though. :)  If you have the right to downgrade to 2008R2 depends on the type of Windows 2012 licence you bought. What kind did you buy?

Comment: First off you would still require a 2008 R2 license.  Have you tried caompatability mode?  Second I am not aware of a downgrade program offered by Microsoft with their Windows Server products.

Comment: @Ramhound MS has long offered Server downgrade rights.  In the past one would require Volume Licensing though.

Comment: Here's the documentation and some reference in case anyone wants to dig out an answer: http://microsoftlicensereview.com/tag/windows-server-2012-downgrade-rights/, http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/briefs/downgrade-rights.aspx, http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/product-licensing.aspx#tab=2

Comment: Yes;  might be the reason I aware.  Aware of their consumer product line rights though